# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds and etc

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

Iam going crazy , i want to insert a value in stuff tabale but i get this error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'name,describe,price,picname) values ('dfg','dfgdf','2','hr')' at line 1
```

my code is :

```
mysql_query("insert into stuff(name,describe,price,picname) values ('dfg','dfgdf','2','hr')") or die("cannot execute the query" .mysql_error());
```

What can i do ? it waste 1 hour of my work !
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding a space between `stuff` and the opening bracket for the field list?

Comment: Put space here `stuff (name,describe,price,picname)`

Comment: yes , but i get the same error !

Comment: describe is also a reserved keyword

Comment: Please show the definition of table 'stuff'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
mysql_query("insert into stuff (`name`,`describe`,`price`,`picname`) values ('dfg','dfgdf','2','hr')") or die("cannot execute the query" .mysql_error());
```

Enclose your column names in backticks since `describe` is a reserved word.

Comment: Totally missed that, haha. +1

Comment: +1. But it is much better not to use reserved words as field names

Comment: Or better yet, change your column name. That will keep your SQL more universal. (_I was too slow_)

Comment: please tell me what the keyword is reserved by mysql ?

Comment: It is reserved for [DESCRIBE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/describe.html)

Comment: See also [MySQL Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's an error in SQL, you can copy this sql statement and execute it in My SQL directly and check it out.

The problem may be in the single qoutes of 2 since it's number.

```
mysql_query("insert into stuff(name,describe,price,picname) values ('dfg','dfgdf',2,'hr')") or die("cannot execute the query" .mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

`DESCRIBE` is a Mysql keyword. See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/describe.html).

Comment: please tell me what the keyword is reserved by mysql ?

Comment: @user1178177 Just follow the link.